# How to force PhpStorm to highlight HTML code in *.php files

Tags: phpstorm

I encountered an issue in PhpStorm IDE. I have some HTML Code in *.php file that doesn't format properly.

How can I force HTML syntax highlighting in particular `*.php` files?

[image: PhpStorm issue]

[image]

Comment: Try to navigate to *File | Settings | Editor | File Types*, find PHPT, and exclude *layout.php* pattern from the list.

Comment: It should work already: works fine for me. Please do this: locate the file where it does not work in the Project View panel; select that file there and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` (`Ctrl+Q` o Windows) -- show what the popup shows for that file. You definitely have something wrong with your settings, must have *somehow accidentally* assigned it to another file type...

Comment: I added an screenshot at the first post

Comment: @s0xzwasd That causes layout.php file disappears from my project pane in PHP Storm

Comment: Does it happen with other colour schemes?

Comment: for testing purposes i swtiched back to dracula default theme no changes.

Comment: @AdrianeZ-programuj 1) `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- Do you have such file name pattern entry for `Auto-detect file type by content`? If you do -- remove it. 2) `Settings/Preferences  | Editor | TextMate Bundles` -- try disabling entry for `php` (it is useless in PhpStorm that has dedicated PHP plugin)..

Comment: I don't have pattern entry for Auto-detect file type by content. I disabled entry for php does not help

Comment: This case is really weird. Have you tried asking in [JetBrains forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm)?

Comment: @AdrianeZ-programuj 1) Show what you have then. 2) What's your IDE version?

Comment: I have the same problem here : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403491207698-How-to-colorize-HTML-code-in-php-files